How to know which components of piezoelectric tensor vanish according to the poling direction?
If the piezoelectric material has a polarization in direction 3 (thickness direction), $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ stress tensors can produce electric displacement $D$ in only direction 3; And $T_5$ (or $T_4$) generates piezoelectric effect in only direction 1 (or 2); $T_6$ has no piezoelectric effect. Reference of information if the link didn't work: (ENERGY HARVESTER APPLICATION OF LARGE DEFORMATION-
PIEZOELECTRICS WITH SYNCHRONIZED-MECHANICAL-SWITCH CIRCUIT
by
Qiaoyi Wei)
Can you please help me understand how I can know which components of the piezoelectric tensor $d$ will vanish according to the poling direction?

